# Trying to pass a dictionary of functions fails in python when using a separate file for data

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have three files; one that contains a test, one that contains data, and one that contains the instructions to run the test.

base.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Base(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def is_true(self):
        return True
```

datadrv.py

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    """
    Parse the data provided in scenarios.
    """
    idlist = []
    argvalues = []
    for scenario in metafunc.cls.scenarios:
        idlist.append(scenario[0])
        items = scenario[1].items()
        argnames = [x[0] for x in items]
        argvalues.append(([x[1] for x in items]))
    metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, ids=idlist)
###
# EDIT BELOW
# ADD NEW SCENARIOS
###

scenario1 = ('ACME_Manage_Keys', { 'org': 'ACME_Corporation', 
                                   'perm_name': 'ManageAcmeCorp', 
                                   'resource': 'activation_keys',
                                   'verbs': ('manage_all',),
                                   'allowed': {"test1": is_true}})
```

test_execute.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lib.base import Base
import pytest
from unittestzero import Assert
from data.datadrv import *

class TestDictionarySupport(object):
    scenarios = [scenario1]

    def test_datadriven_support(self,
            org,
            perm_name,
            resource,
            verbs,
            allowed):

        base = Base()

        functionToCall = allowed['test1']
        Assert.true(base.functionToCall())
        """ THIS WORKS, uncomment the block to see """
        """
        Assert.true(base.is_true())
        """
```

My end goal is to have `Assert.true(base.is_true())` however every attempt I have made has resulted in either TypeErrors or NameErrors.  What am I missing here or doing wrong?

To reproduce the above simply create 3 directories; lib, data, and tests.  Place the test_execute.py in tests, datadrv.py in data and the base.py in lib.  You will need pytest and unittestzero to run.  From the root directory you can run py.test.

Note: when I have this much working I will have a for loop and multiple tests so `functionToCall = allowed['test1']` will become something like `functionToCall = key[value]`

Also, my starting reference point is http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65126-dictionary-of-methodsfunctions/.

Thank you and errors follow:

**NOTE** the errors differ by approach attempted.

With `'allowed': {'test1': Base.is_true}})`: 
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** ERROR collecting tests/test_execute.py ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
tests/test_execute.py:6: in

> from data.datadrv import *
>   data/datadrv.py:22: in 
>                                        'allowed': {'test1': Base.is_true}})
>   E   NameError: name 'Base' is not defined
>   ==================================================== 1 error in 0.02 seconds =====================================================

With `'allowed': {'test1': base.is_true}})`:
tests/test_execute.py:6: in

> from data.datadrv import *
>   data/datadrv.py:22: in 
>                                        'allowed': {'test1': base.is_true}})
>   E   NameError: name 'base' is not defined

With `Assert.true(base.functionToCall())`:

tests/test_execute.py:6: in

> from data.datadrv import *
>   data/datadrv.py:22: in 
>                                        'allowed': {'test1': is_true}})
>   E   NameError: name 'is_true' is not defined

Comment: Post your error messages and traceback

Comment: Updated with the appropriate import.

Comment: The error depends on the approach, if I use 'allowed': {'test1': base.is_true} I get nothing more than a nameerror.

`tests/test_execute.py:6: in <module>
>   from data.datadrv import *
data/datadrv.py:22: in <module>
>                                      'allowed': {'test1': Base.is_true}})
E   NameError: name 'Base' is not defined
==================================================== 1 error in 0.02 seconds ==================================================`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `Base.is_true` and `is_true`, the first one is a method of the object `Base`, the second one is an undefined function in your code. You can have a dictionary of methods and call them like this:

```
d = {'test1': Base.is_true}
f = d['test1']
f(base)
```

This way you call the method and give `base` as an argument `self`.

Comment: I have tried this, this approach fails with: E   NameError: name 'Base' is not defined.  

In data/datadrv.py I modified allowed to read 'allowed': {'test1': Base.is_true}}), also tried with base.is_true.  The issue here is without quotes python is expecting Base.is_true to be something.  The challenge here that is different from my reference is that I am using multiple files instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an 'import Base' line to datadrv.py.

That will resolve the 'Base is not defined' error, so you can use {'test1': Base.is_true}